# Simulation of reflected particles

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, simulation, canvas

I made a particle simulation in vanilla JavaScript. It can currently handle around 10000 particles (staying 58-60 fps on my machine).

For testing, controls are MB1, MB2, R, Z.

How can I make this more efficient?

```js
var width, height;
var head = [];
var hcount = parseInt(prompt("PARTICLE COUNT? <Default: 10000>")) || 10000;
var speed = parseFloat(prompt("PARTICLE SPEED? <Default: 3")) || 3;
var mousePos = {x:400, y:400};
var pullStr = 10;
var pullDist = -2000;
var mdown = false; //left mbutton
var rmdown = false; //right mbutton
var running = true; //running or paused
var tempLineSt = {x:0,y:0};
var lastL = new Date;
var fps = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var fpsCounter = 0;

function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    width=1400;
    height=900;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle="#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle="#ff0000";

    //collision lines, [x1,y1,x2,y2]
    lines = [[0,30,1400,30], [1370,0,1370,900], [1400,870,0,870], [30,900,30,0],

    [0,60,60,0], [1340,0,1400,60], [1400,840,1340,900], [60,900,0,840]];

    for(i = 0; i < hcount; i++){
        head[i] = {x:500, y:500, dir: Math.random()*2*Math.PI};
    }

    setInterval(gameloop, 16);
}

function gameloop(){

    //monitor fps
    var thisL = new Date;
    fps.push(1000 / (thisL - lastL));
    fps.shift();
    lastL = thisL;

    draw();
    if(running)
        calc();
}

function draw(){
    //blur effect
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle="#c4c4c4";
    ctx.fillRect(30, 30, width - 60, height - 60);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    for(i = 0; i < hcount; i++){
        ctx.fillRect(head[i].x, head[i].y, 3, 3);
    }

    //hide dirty corner-collision bugs :D
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,1400,30);
    ctx.fillRect(1370,0,30,900);
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,30,900);
    ctx.fillRect(0,870,1370,30);

    //draw lines
    ctx.strokeStyle="gray";
    for(j = 0; j < lines.length; j++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lines[j][0], lines[j][1]);
        ctx.lineTo(lines[j][2], lines[j][3]);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    if(rmdown){
        ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
        ctx.moveTo(tempLineSt.x, tempLineSt.y);
        ctx.lineTo(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    //display fps
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    var sum = 0;
    for(var k = 0; k < 50; k++){
        sum += fps[k];
    }
    var fpsAvg = sum/50;
    ctx.font="30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(Math.round(fpsAvg), 50, 70)

}

function calc(){
    var TmousePos = mousePos;
    for(i = 0; i < hcount; i++){

        var dx = Math.sin(head[i].dir)*speed;
        var dy = Math.cos(head[i].dir)*speed;

        head[i].x += dx;
        head[i].y -= dy;

        if(mdown){
            var vectToM = [TmousePos.x - head[i].x, TmousePos.y - head[i].y];
            var dist = (Math.sqrt((vectToM[0])*(vectToM[0]) + (vectToM[1])*(vectToM[1])));
            var vectToMAngle = Math.acos(-vectToM[1]/dist);

            if(TmousePos.x < head[i].x)
                vectToMAngle = 2*Math.PI - vectToMAngle;

            if(Math.random() < dist/pullDist){
                head[i].dir += (vectToMAngle - head[i].dir)/pullStr;
            }
        }
        //collisions
        for(j = 0; j < lines.length; j++){
            var x = head[i].x;
            var y = head[i].y;
            if(line_intersects(lines[j][0], lines[j][1], lines[j][2], lines[j][3], x, y, x+dx, y-dy)){
                //line Vector
                lv = [lines[j][2] - lines[j][0], lines[j][1] - lines[j][3]];
                dotlvDir = lv[0]*dx + lv[1]*dy;
                dotlvlv = lv[0]*lv[0] + lv[1]*lv[1];
                dotDiv = dotlvDir/dotlvlv;
                //dir vect: [dx,-dy]
                projlvDir = [dotDiv*lv[0], dotDiv*lv[1]];

                newVec = [2*projlvDir[0] - dx, 2*projlvDir[1] - dy];
                head[i].dir = Math.atan2(newVec[0],newVec[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

function resetParticles(x,y){
    for(i = 0; i < hcount; i++){
        head[i].x = x;
        head[i].y = y;
        head[i].dir = 2*i*Math.PI/hcount;
    }
}

//Joncom on github
function line_intersects(p0_x, p0_y, p1_x, p1_y, p2_x, p2_y, p3_x, p3_y) {

    var s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y;
    s1_x = p1_x - p0_x;
    s1_y = p1_y - p0_y;
    s2_x = p3_x - p2_x;
    s2_y = p3_y - p2_y;

    var s, t;
    s = (-s1_y * (p0_x - p2_x) + s1_x * (p0_y - p2_y)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);
    t = ( s2_x * (p0_y - p2_y) - s2_y * (p0_x - p2_x)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);

    return (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1)
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
    mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {

if(evt.button === 0){
    mdown = true;
    pullStr = 1;
    pullDist = 500;
}
else if(evt.button === 2){
    rmdown = true;
    tempLineSt.x = mousePos.x;
    tempLineSt.y = mousePos.y;
}

}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt) {

    mdown = false;
    pullStr = 14;
    pullDist = -2000;

if(evt.button === 2){
    rmdown = false;
    lines.push([tempLineSt.x, tempLineSt.y, mousePos.x, mousePos.y]);
}

}, false);

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
if(evt.keyCode == 32)
    running = !running;
if(evt.keyCode == 82)
    resetParticles(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
if(evt.keyCode == 90){
    if(lines.length > 8)
        lines.pop();
}
}, false);

document.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); return false; }, false);

init();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Also, in Chrome the particles jitter a bit every 0.5 seconds or so - yet in Edge there is no jitter. What gives?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious to optimize noticeably, the [profiler shows fillRect](https://puu.sh/ruz4a/9b957aebc0.png) consuming most of the CPU, next is [Math.atan2 in calc](https://puu.sh/ruz9z/65d1ca1d38.png) (I've cached head[i], x, y to eliminate the obvious optimization candidate). So to speedup considerably you would need a better algorithm. Maybe direct pixel array modification that would allow to eliminate huge amount of fillRect function calls - invocation overhead is big in js.